# Using the image in the description, how can I calculate the measurements of the robot?

Tags: science-based, physics

For reference, I’ve decided that the blue sphere in the image is Earth and the robot is hovering at 375 miles above sea level. From there, what steps would I need to follow to calculate the robot’s height and wingspan?

Edit #1:
I’ve been told that I didn’t give an apparently important piece of data, that being the distance between the robot and the ‘camera’. So, I’ll say that the distance is 325 miles away from the robot.

Edit #2:
I’ve changed the distance between the camera and the robot from 750 miles to 325 miles.

Edit #3:
I’ve been told that the altitude of the camera is another necessary detail. For this, I’ll say the camera is at an altitude of 625 Miles.

[image]

Comment: I actually did design the robot.

Comment: The question does not provide enough data to compute an answer. (Because we don't know how far from the robot is the photo camera. It may be the case that the camera is very close to the robot, and the robot is a very small toy; it may be the case that the camera is very far from the robot and the robot is about 3000 km tall. Photographers and cinematographers often make use of [forced perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_perspective); here is [a pretty typical example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Europe_2007_Disk_1_340.jpg).)

Comment: Interesting you're asking the size of the mech' *after* you designed and drew it, but ok! Just an artistic note : supposing you're not blinded by the sun because it's (much) cooler, it's quite likely you'll see it engulfed in dark shadows, due to the backlighting :).

Comment: It seems like you're asking about calculating the dimensions of a robot from an existing work of fiction. Such questions about third party worlds are off topic on this site. We're here to help you build your own world, not speculate about a world somebody has already built.

Comment: Uh, what? The robot isn’t from the work of someone else.

Comment: As I already said, I designed it.

Comment: Then you should already know how big it is.

Comment: I fail to see how I should already know how big it is.

Comment: To me, to design something means to come up with its shape and appearance. That’s about it. Anything regarding the actual size of it comes after that.

Comment: Enough witty banter.  OP asks for a calculaton.  This is calculable but I cannot calculate it; I tried..    We have distances and the observed curvature of the earth.  If someone would post answer with calculation I will upvote and bounty.

Comment: @Sphennings I've reverse-searched the picture just in case, I haven't found a similar design nor artstyle. So yes, it's surprising for us worldbuilders who does it the other way round, but the querent is indeed asking for their robot, not 3rd party :).

Comment: @Willk Yeah, at this point, I’ve asked it somewhere more fitting. There’s more details there.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4585181/1123929 Here’s the link, btw.

Comment: After some thoughts I've retracted my close-vote. It's kinda worldbuilding in a way, just not one we're used to see ^^.

Comment: Use the metric system. Death to imperial units!

Comment: You only need two things to figure out the size of the robot: focal length and angle-of-view. Here's a quick and dirty description of those: https://marshall-usa.com/blog/how-to/camera-focal-lengths-and-angle-of-view-aov-explained/
Once you have those two, it's a simple matter of trigonometry. The curve of the planet behind it is a red herring. Once you've determined the previous two, it will tell you the altitude at which the image was generated, not the size of the robot.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>All pixel measurements in this answer refer to the full size image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXfh8.jpg.) One can of course print out the image and work in centimeters (or inches) instead of pixels, but when working on screen pixels come natural.)</sub>

<sub>Whenever I speak of the position of the camera, I mean the [station point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station_point). But I didn't feel that somebody who asks how to calculate the scale at which a subject is shown in a picture would know what that is.</sub>

- The radius of the blurry blue sphere supposed to be Earth is about 12,000 pixels. (I hope you know how to compute the radius of a circle when given an arc of the circle.)
- The robot is about 2,200 pixels tall.
- Warning: gross approximations ahead, but I don't feel like going into full trigonometry.
- The real radius of the Earth, call it $R$, is about 6,400 km.
- The camera is at 6,400 + 600 + 1,200 = 8,200 km from the center of the Earth. Let's call $h_c$ the height of the camera above sea level, or in our case 1,800 km.
- From that distance, the visible part of the Earth is a circle with a radius $r = R \times \cos (\arcsin(R / (R + h_c)))$, or in our case about 4,000 km.
- So that 4,000 km seen at a distance from the camera of $h_c$ = 1,800 km correspond to 12,000 pixels.
- If the robot would be at the same distance from the camera, its 2,200 pixels would correspond to (2,200 / 12,000) × 4,000 = 733 km.
- But the robot is closer, to that to cover the same angular size its height must be smaller in the proportion of the distance, 733 × (1,200 / 1,800) = 489 km.
- Overall, the robot is about 500 km or 300 miles tall.

How to think about this computation:

1. Determine the pixel height of the robot and the pixel radius of the disk representing the Earth.
2. Knowing the real radius of the Earth and the height above sea level of the camera, determine the real radius of the disk representing the Earth.
3. Now you know the scale at which the blue disk is shown in the image.
4. The scale at which the robot is shown in the image will be roughly in the proportion of the distance between the robot and the camera over the height of the camera above sea level.

Comment: And about 550km from one arm to another as seen on the picture, since the width is almost 2500px (2500 / 2200 x 489 km = ~550km)